# Linq order by Area Name with one exception

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Hi say I have objects of type Area with Names:

Hokitika
Dunedin
Stewart Island
West Coast
Invercargill

and I want to order them by name I could go:

```
areas.OrderBy(a => a.Name)
```

to give me:

Dunedin
Hokitika
Invercargill
Stewart Island
West Coast

which is fine but what say I was wanting to make this to be an ordered list with the exception that the current users location was at the top so if they were in Invercargill the list would be:

Invercargill
Dunedin
Hokitika
Stewart Island
West Coast

Is this possible in Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can order by a bool:

```
areas.OrderByDescending(a => a.Equals(myArea, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     .ThenBy(a => a.Name);
```

If that doesn't work on your DB, you can try:

```
areas.Select(a => new { IsMyLocation = a.Equals(myArea, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
                        Area = a })
     .OrderByDescending (a => a.IsMyLocation)
     .Select(a => a.Area);
```

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of ThenBy until now.

Answer (score 0):

```
string currentLocation = "Invercatgill"; // for instance

var sortedresult = areas.OrderBy(a => a.Name.Equals(currentLocation) ? 0 : 1)
                        .ThenBy(a => a.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it using `Except`

```
var currentLocation = new [] { user.CurrentLocation };

var otherAreas = areas.Except(currentLocation).OrderBy(x => x.Name)

var finalResult = currentLocation.Concat(otherAreas);
```